# Allow button click even if validation on another control fails

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an interesting problem that I don't know how to solve. I wrote a form which does a password change. The form displays the current password too in a read-only TextBox (not for validation purposes; this isn't important in this case.) Each password TextBox has a button in it that when clicked, masks or unmasks the password (replacing the password characters with bullets and vice versa.) Here's an image of the whole thing:

[image: screenshot]

Notice how the mask/unmask buttons are inside the text boxes, not outside of them. The buttons have been placed inside the text boxes with:

```
var button = new Button();
button.Width = 20;
button.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
button.Image = SystemIcons.Shield.ToBitmap();
button.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
button.CausesValidation = false;
textBox.Controls.Add(button);
```

The last TextBox has validation enabled. Now the problem is, that the user is unable to click the passwork unmask button on the other text box, because the validation event fails. Thus, the user is unable to see the current password without entering a new one.

I need a way to have the password mask/unmask button be clickable even if validation is failing in the text box. I can't think of anything. Moving those buttons outside the text boxes is not an option.

The unmask buttons themselves, as well as the parents of the text boxes, all have `CausesValidation` set to `false`. Only the text boxes themselves have it set to `true`.

This is a .NET 2.0 C# project in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: As an aside, this would suggest the password is stored in clear text, so you can display it. That would be a bad thing.

Comment: @SimonHalsey The password needs to be readable and copy&paste-able. It's the same sort of thing as the "show password" button in many web browsers. If you go to their configuration page where you get a list of previously stored passwords, they are masked by default but there's a "show" button that shows them in plain text. I need to do the exact same thing here.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but it's still bad practice. It's why the Sony hack & many others were so devastating. Browsers are slightly different in that they aren't persistent storage for a system. It's also bad practice as well doing that.

Comment: @SimonHalsey: Well, it's impossible to do this in any other way. So even if it's bad, it's the only available option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a way where I can keep using the Validating event and still be able to click the buttons in the other text boxes. It turns out that the Button.MouseUp event is sent even if a button doesn't have focus.

So the solution is to handle both the MouseUp as well as the Click event and perform the password masking/unmasking depending on whether the text box that contains the button currently has keyboard focus or not:

```
button.MouseUp += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (button.Parent.ContainsFocus || e.Button != MouseButtons.Left
        || !button.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        return;
    }
    textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = !textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar;
};

button.Click += delegate
{
    if (!button.Parent.ContainsFocus) {
        return;
    }
    textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = !textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar;
};
```

We do want to handle both events, because if we only handle MouseUp, then clicking the buttons with the keyboard (Tab to switch to the button, and Enter or Space to click it) would not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to do it with the `Validating` event of the text box. The click event will not even reach the button when the text box loses focus. I'm thinking that you could either create your own TextBox (by extending TextBox or TextBoxBase) and hack the validation behavior there or override the form's `DefWndProc` and catch the mouse events + associated info (coordinates) there and still dispatch them (could get ugly) when validation fails.

One easy way out is to not rely on the `Validating` event anymore. Instead do the validation in the `Leave` event of the text box and if it fails just mark the text box as such. The user will still see there is a problem.

One more thing you need to take care of is the `OK` button of the dialog. You need to make sure the user won't be able to close the dialog if there are unvalidated controls on the form. Since you don't have validation support anymore, maybe you can use the `Tag` property to store a `False` (for example) when the data is not valid. On `OK` just iterate over all textboxes and check their tags.

The behavior for the end user will ultimately be the same, you just have to write a bit more code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This sounds like a good plan. If no other answers come up in the next hour or so that would somehow provide a solution that doesn't get rid of the Validating event, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one :-)

Comment: @NikosC.: No problem. You might want to give the `Tag` suggestion some more thought. There may be an easier solution for storing the valid state of the entire form.

Comment: That's already there, actually. Every text box sets a flag to true if it contains valid data. As you can see from the screenshot, the OK button is disabled by default and only gets enabled once all text boxes contain valid data.

Comment: I've found a way to do this with the Validating event in place (see answer.) It turned out to be so easy, it's actually kinda funny :-P